# How to get span tag parent class name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags, jsdom

```
<div class="todo"> <h3>Have to understand js DOM</h3>
        <div class="ed-btn">
          <span id="delete" onclick="deleteTodo(event)"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
          </span>`; </div>

const deleteTodo = event => {   console.log(event.currentTarget); };
```

by onclicking deleteTodo(event) i just found

```
      <span id="delete" onclick="deleteTodo(event)"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
```

but How could i get the class 'todo' or the h3's inner content?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the text 'Some text' to trigger the listener ;)

Pretty straightforward:

`parentElement` allows you to get the parent element.

`className` will get you the classes of the node.

`innerText` will get you... the inner text ;)

```js
const deleteTodo = event => { 
  const target = event.currentTarget;
  const root = target.parentElement.parentElement;
  console.log('root class:', root.className);
  console.log('h3 content:', root.querySelector('h3').innerText); 
};
```

```html
<div class="todo"> 
  <h3>Have to understand js DOM</h3>
  <div class="ed-btn">
    <span id="delete" onclick="deleteTodo(event)">
      <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
      Some text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hoping it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the parent of a tag you can use the parentElement method like so:

`document.getElementById("delete").parentElement`

[more in docs here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp)

However, you can just access the h3 or todo element directly:

`document.getElementsByClassName("todo")`

[more on that here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)